# Using NSDirectoryEnumerator to model the filesystem

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, macos, enumeration, enumerator

I'm trying to model the structure of the filesystem from a given starting path. The goal is to create a standard `NSOutlineView` of the filesystem from that path onwards.

I've got a model object called `fileSystemItem`. It has the following (very standard) relationships and properties:

- `parentItem`   (points to another `fileSystemItem` object)
- `isLeaf`       (`YES` for files; `NO` for folders)
- `childrenItems` (array of other `fileSystemItems`)
- `fullPath` (`NSString`; file path of object)

My question is: how do I use `NSDirectoryEnumerator` to build the model? If I do this:

```
// NOTE: can't do "while (file = [dirEnum nextObject]) {...} because that sets 
// file to an auto-released string that doesn't get released until after ALL 
// iterations of the loop are complete. For large directories, that means our 
// memory use spikes to hundreds of MBs. So we do this instead to ensure that 
// the "file" string is released at the end of each iteration and our overall 
// memory footprint stays low.

NSDirectoryEnumerator *dirEnum = [aFileManager enumeratorAtPath:someStartingPath];
BOOL keepRunning = YES;
while (keepRunning)
{
    NSAutoreleasePool *innerPool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];

    NSString *file = [dirEnum nextObject];
    if (file == nil) break;

    // ... examine "file". Create a fileSystemItem object to represent this item.
    // If it's a folder, we need to create a fileSystemItem for each item in the folder
    // and each fileSystemItem's "parentItem" relationship needs to be set to the 
    // fileSystemItem we're creating right here for "file." How can I do this inside
    // the directoryEnumerator, because as soon as we go to the next iteration of the    
    // loop (to handle the first item in "file" if "file" is a folder), we lose the  
    // reference to the fileSystemItem we created in THIS iteration of the loop for 
    // "file". Hopefully that makes sense... 

    [innerPool drain];
}
```

I can see how to build the model if I write a recursive function that looks at each item in `startingPath` and, if that item is a folder, calls itself again on that folder and so on. But how can I build the model with `NSDirectoryEnumerator`? I mean, supposedly that's why the class exists, right?

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to use another kind of directory enumeration:

`enumeratorAtURL:includingPropertiesForKeys:options:errorHandler:`

This enumerator has additional useful options and allows to iterate NSURL instances with prefetched attributes, such as `NSURLNameKey`, `NSURLIsDirectoryKey`, `NSURLParentDirectoryURLKey`, etc... It could help to get rid of recursion usage.

Answer (score -2):

If that file is a directory, you'll need to create a new directory enumerator; an NSDirectoryEnumerator enumerates one directory, not every directory on the system.
So yes, you'll have to use recursion.